# AutoMapper with Unity: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have configure Automapper with Microsoft Unity Framework but when I am trying to do mapping like below mentioned code  Then I am getting **"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."**

```
var orderResponse = this.Mapper.Map<Order, OrderV1>(order);
```

I am not able to figure out where Exactly I am doing Mistakes.

I have followed below mentioned steps

1. Profile Creation

   `public class OrderProfile : Profile
       {
           public OrderProfile()
           {
               Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderV1>()
                   .ReverseMap();

       }
      }`

2.Registration of Unity Container

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var container = InitializeUnity();
//Automapper Profile Registration 
    container.RegisterAutoMapperType(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

}
 public static IUnityContainer InitializeUnity()
  {
            using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
            {
        ------------
        ------------
        return container ;
        }
  }
```

3.Extension Method For Profile Registration

```
public static class UnityExtensions
    {
        public static void RegisterAutoMapperType(this IUnityContainer container, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager = null)
        {
            RegisterAutoMapperProfiles(container);

            var profiles = container.ResolveAll<Profile>();
            var autoMapperConfigurationStore = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);
            profiles.Each(autoMapperConfigurationStore.AddProfile);
            autoMapperConfigurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            container.RegisterInstance<IConfigurationProvider>(autoMapperConfigurationStore, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(autoMapperConfigurationStore, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ConfigurationStore, ConfigurationStore>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITypeMapFactory), MapperRegistry.Mappers));
            container.RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider, ConfigurationStore>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationStore>();
            container.RegisterType<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>();
            container.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>(lifetimeManager ?? new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IConfigurationProvider)));
        }

        private static void RegisterAutoMapperProfiles(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> autoMapperProfileTypes = AllClasses.FromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                           .Where(type => type != typeof(Profile) && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type));

            autoMapperProfileTypes.Each(autoMapperProfileType =>
                container.RegisterType(typeof(Profile),
                autoMapperProfileType,
                autoMapperProfileType.FullName,
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionMember[0]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Profile, call CreateMap, not Mapper.CreateMap, and override Configure

```
public class OrderProfile : Profile {
    protected override void Configure() {
        base.CreateMap<Order, OrderV1>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jimmy Bogard: Still I am getting same error.Please see detail steps which I am following in code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370013/automapper-with-unity-configuration-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsuppor